# bind a input value to a style of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, binding

I have the following code

```html
<input id="in" value="50px"/>
<div id="out">this is my output</div>
```

how to bind using the jquery the `#in` value to the `#out`'s `font-size`?

Constraints:

a) the variant from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/gqGErw?editors=1010) should also work:

```
$(function() {  
  $("#out").css("fontSize", $("#in").val());

  $("#in").on("input", function(e) {
    $("#out").css("fontSize", $("#in").val());
  });

  $("#in").val("5px"); // should update the font size! 
});
```

b) when the browser is **autofill**-ing the values into the boxes, the value should change...

Comment: Use [`on('input', fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css). If you want specific help, please edit the question to include your own attempts to solve this.

Comment: (1) read the value of the input (2) set the font size [do this for each input change]

Comment: could someone explain the downwotes?

Comment: updated the OP, added constraints

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply your CSS with the [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function from JQuery when the event gets fired (here keyup).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in" value="18px"/>
<div id="out">this is my output</div>
<script>
$('#in').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#out').css({'font-size':$(this).val()});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.css` function of jquery

```js
$('#in').keyup(function() {
  $("#out").css('font-size', $('#in').val()+"px")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in" value="18" />
<br><br>
<br>

<div id="out">this is my output</div>
```

Comment: why everybody uses the keyup event? actually it will no work just lauching the application

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript:

```js
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
const out = document.querySelector("#out");

inp.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  out.style.fontSize = inp.value + "px";
})
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" placeholder="write a value">
<div id="out">this is my output</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

You will need to validate the information before change the font size:

```
<input id="in" value="18px"/>
<div id="out">this is my output</div>  
$(function() {
    $("#in").on('input',function(e){
    $("#out").css("fontSize", $("#in").val());
  });

});  
https://jsfiddle.net/3vhdfruq/1/
```

Comment: works only if the field is focused, and an input is performed

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get it. Do you want to change when loaded? Just call "$("#out").css("fontSize", $("#in").val());" when the script is loaded...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
var out = document.querySelector("#out");

inp.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  out.style.fontSize = inp.value + "px";
})
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" value="20">
<div id="out">this is my output</div>
```

Comment: keyup dependent